# Where does `__assert` come from?

Tags: c, glibc

When reading glibc sources I stumbled upon this comment in [assert.h](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/assert/assert.h):

```
/* The following is not at all used here but needed for standard
   compliance.  */
extern void __assert (const char *__assertion, const char *__file, int __line)
     __THROW __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

What standard specifies a `__assert` function?

I couldn't find anything in POSIX or C or in git commit history or find on the net or on this site.

Comment: I randomly found this [mention](https://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/avr/documentation/index.htm?https://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/avr/documentation/__assert.htm), but note that in C89 there wasn't `__func__`, so the [assert](http://jfxpt.com/library/c89-draft.html#4.2) macro *"writes information about the particular call that failed (including the text of the argument, the name of the source file, and the source line number"*. Both `__assert_fail` and `__assert_perror_fail` have a `const char *__function` argument, this hasn't.

Comment: It looks like it was [added by Ulrich Drepper in 2000](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.1.92/source/ChangeLog#L148).

Comment: There's probably some context missing here. The Standard requires an assert() function, not an __assert() function. Maybe there's a macro or compiler magic somewhere that turns assert() into __assert().

Comment: All identifiers containing `__` (double unsderscore) are reserved for use by the implementation.  So glibc (part of the GNU C implementation) can freely use names like `__assert` for any internal thing it wants, knowing it will never collide with any use by a standard-conforming program or library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this digging through the mailing list: [glibc should be Sys V ABI compliant, hence implement __assert()](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-bugs/2000-July/038375.html).

> ABI standards, though not as important as source standards, are still
> standards.
>
> The System V ABI (available from
> ftp://ftp.linux.sgi.com/pub/linux/mips/doc/ABI and elsewhere)
> specifies a function __assert
>
> I think both gcc (in libgcc) and glibc (in libc.a) should implement
> __assert.
>
> If its existence in a standard is not a good enough reason, here is an
> actual bug:  this is required to allow glibc to replace libc on
> Solaris.  Certainly glibcers will consider this a noble goal.
>
> Quote: "Porting the library is not hard."  Consider this a start of
> the Solaris port.
>
> Of course, glibc also needs to implement other symbols in
> Solaris libc for binary compatibility with Solaris.  If they are not
> already in glibc, most can probably be copied from libgcc.

In [System V ABI Edition 4.1](https://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) pp. 6-9:

> **Figure 6-6**: `libc` Contents, Internal Names without Synonyms
>
> `_cleanup` `_xftw` `__flsbuf` `__trwctype*` `_tolower` `__assert` `__iswctype*` `___errno*` `_toupper` `__filbuf` `__thr_errno*`